# Converting dates to days with different starting dates in one data frame

Tags: r, date

I'm having some trouble trying to do a count of days based on starting dates. I basically just want a count of days passed since the starting date by product.

I think it is best illustrated by example.
**This is what I start with:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(Dates = seq(as.Date("2021/1/1"), as.Date("2021/1/15"), "days"),
                  Product = rep(c(rep("Banana", 5), rep("Apple", 5), rep("Orange", 5)))
                  )
        Dates Product
1  2021-01-01  Banana
2  2021-01-02  Banana
3  2021-01-03  Banana
4  2021-01-04  Banana
5  2021-01-05  Banana
6  2021-01-06   Apple
7  2021-01-07   Apple
8  2021-01-08   Apple
9  2021-01-09   Apple
10 2021-01-10   Apple
11 2021-01-11  Orange
12 2021-01-12  Orange
13 2021-01-13  Orange
14 2021-01-14  Orange
15 2021-01-15  Orange
```

I currently have several measurements for each product that I need to plot as number of days rather than dates and I cannot make the transformation.

**And this is what I want:**

```
desired_df <- data.frame(Dates = seq(as.Date("2021/1/1"), as.Date("2021/1/15"), "days"),
                         Product = rep(c(rep("Banana", 5), rep("Apple", 5), rep("Orange", 5))),
                         Days = rep(seq(0, 4), 3)
)
        Dates Product Days
1  2021-01-01  Banana    0
2  2021-01-02  Banana    1
3  2021-01-03  Banana    2
4  2021-01-04  Banana    3
5  2021-01-05  Banana    4
6  2021-01-06   Apple    0
7  2021-01-07   Apple    1
8  2021-01-08   Apple    2
9  2021-01-09   Apple    3
10 2021-01-10   Apple    4
11 2021-01-11  Orange    0
12 2021-01-12  Orange    1
13 2021-01-13  Orange    2
14 2021-01-14  Orange    3
15 2021-01-15  Orange    4
```

So far I've tried a few approaches, but none works.

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Days = Dates - Dates[1])


df3 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(Product) %>% 
  mutate(Days = Dates - Dates[1])
        Dates Product    Days


starter_dates <- df1 %>% 
  aggregate(by = list(df1$Product), FUN = first)
  Group.1      Dates Product
1   Apple 2021-01-06   Apple
2  Banana 2021-01-01  Banana
3  Orange 2021-01-11  Orange

df4 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    Days = case_when(Product == starter_dates$Product ~ Dates - starter_dates$Dates)
  )
```

But none produced what I want. How can I calculate the number of days from first appearance?

EDIT:

This is what I get from suggested answers:

```
> df1 %>% group_by(Product) %>% mutate(Days = as.numeric(Dates - Dates[1]))
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   Product [3]
   Dates      Product  Days
   <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
 1 2021-01-01 Banana      0
 2 2021-01-02 Banana      1
 3 2021-01-03 Banana      2
 4 2021-01-04 Banana      3
 5 2021-01-05 Banana      4
 6 2021-01-06 Apple       5
 7 2021-01-07 Apple       6
 8 2021-01-08 Apple       7
 9 2021-01-09 Apple       8
10 2021-01-10 Apple       9
11 2021-01-11 Orange     10
12 2021-01-12 Orange     11
13 2021-01-13 Orange     12
14 2021-01-14 Orange     13
15 2021-01-15 Orange     14
```

Ensuring no conflicts from other packages, below now works.

```
df1 %>% group_by(Product) %>%
        mutate(Days=lubridate::day(Dates)-first(lubridate::day(Dates)))
```

Comment: `df1 %>% group_by(Product) %>% mutate(Days = as.numeric(Dates - Dates[1]))` should work.

Comment: The produced output is not similar to my desired output where it starts counting days again after the first day for the product. And not just the very first day for the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can subtract the "Date", for every row, from the `first` "Date" value:

```
df1 %>% group_by(Product) %>%
        mutate(Days=lubridate::day(Dates)-first(lubridate::day(Dates)))

# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   Product [3]
   Dates      Product  Days
   <date>     <chr>   <int>
 1 2021-01-01 Banana      0
 2 2021-01-02 Banana      1
 3 2021-01-03 Banana      2
 4 2021-01-04 Banana      3
 5 2021-01-05 Banana      4
 6 2021-01-06 Apple       0
 7 2021-01-07 Apple       1
 8 2021-01-08 Apple       2
 9 2021-01-09 Apple       3
10 2021-01-10 Apple       4
11 2021-01-11 Orange      0
12 2021-01-12 Orange      1
13 2021-01-13 Orange      2
14 2021-01-14 Orange      3
15 2021-01-15 Orange      4
```

Comment: This does not give me the desired output.

Even when using `df1` instead of `desired_df`

Comment: This still doesn't work. It produces the same output as I've put in my edit.

Comment: I got my output with the same data.

Comment: I restarted Rstudio and it now works. Possibly some packages interferred.

Answer (score 0):

Since using *tidyverse* is not a requirement, here a **base R** solution:

```
data.frame( df1, Days=as.vector( sapply( unique(df1$Product),
   function(x) df1$Dates[df1$Product==x] - df1$Dates[df1$Product==x][1] ) ) )

        Dates Product Days
1  2021-01-01  Banana    0
2  2021-01-02  Banana    1
3  2021-01-03  Banana    2
4  2021-01-04  Banana    3
5  2021-01-05  Banana    4
6  2021-01-06   Apple    0
7  2021-01-07   Apple    1
8  2021-01-08   Apple    2
9  2021-01-09   Apple    3
10 2021-01-10   Apple    4
11 2021-01-11  Orange    0
12 2021-01-12  Orange    1
13 2021-01-13  Orange    2
14 2021-01-14  Orange    3
15 2021-01-15  Orange    4
```